# Twitter authentication is not working in nextjs using next-auth

Tags: javascript, next.js, oauth, next-auth

Screenshot of the twitter authentication error

[image: 1]

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import TwitterProvider from 'next-auth/providers/twitter'

export default NextAuth({
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        TwitterProvider({
            clientId: process.env.TWITTER_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_SECRET,
            version: '2.0',
        }),
    ],
})
```

and also some errors are showing on the screen

Comment: Console log `process.env.TWITTER_ID` and `process.env.TWITTER_SECRET` and see if they are undefined or not. My guess is your environment variables are undefined.

Comment: Yes, it shows `undefined`, but when I checked for `process.env.GOOGLE_ID` and `process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET` then it also shows `undefined`, but authentication with google is working fine.

Comment: Those environment variables will be undefined on the client-side, they're only available on the server - that's expected.

Comment: _"some errors are showing on the screen"_ - What errors are those?